# Set NDK_MODULE_PATH for cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am deploying my cocos2d-x project in Android Platform. I am getting the following error:

```
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
```

I think there is some problem in setting the path. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue? I am working in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you ran `setup.py` this would have made changes for you.

you chould edit your `.bash_profile` to add something like:

```
####################################
# Cocos2d-x and Android Development 
###################################
# Cocos2d-x console
export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/Users/jtsm/Chukong-Inc/cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable NDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/jtsm/Chukong-Inc/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r9d
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/jtsm/Chukong-Inc/AndroidDev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH

# Add environment variable ANT_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANT_ROOT=/Users/jtsm/Chukong-Inc/AndroidDev/apache-ant-1.9.3/bin
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Android NDK here: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
2. Install it into somefolder folder
3. Edit your ~/.bash_profile to point to that folder. Example:
   export NDKROOT="/Users/you/NVPACK/android-ndk-r9b"